# PostgreSQL Visualiser tools are slow

Tags: postgresql

I just began working with PostgreSQL and have found both pgAdmin and Navicat to be really slow. Its slow to open a database, list the tables and list the first 100 rows. The db I'm looking at is very small and I'm running on a macbook air so I don't see hardware being the problem.

Is this a common issue? Is there a way to speed things up? I've used mysql or sqlite3 and their tools are far quicker.

EDIT: I should also point out that I recently upgraded from OS X Snow Leopard to Lion. Would the default postgreSQL install on Lion cause interference?

Answer (score 1):

[pgAdmin](http://pgadmin.org/) should hardly hesitate to display the first 100 rows (unless you include huge rows). I have been using it daily for the last couple of years.

Unless something is wrong in your installation, the delay is probably due to some other factors like network overhead or excessive load on your database server or local machine.

Old versions have various performance issues. Try upgrading to the current version 1.14.2 in this case.

Just tested with pgAdmin 1.14.2 in Win XP, Server pg 9.1 on Debian Squeeze: "View data" ->"Top 100 rows", table with 25 rows including some longer text columns (3x ~ 150 char), over the net, SSL encrypted. Hardly took a second until the display was complete.

If that happens just with this particular table, it might be an issue with vacuuming. Run a test with [`psql`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/app-psql.html) if that is just as slow. 
Some old versions of pgAdmin are very slow if `bytea` columns are included.

Comment: Perhaps I'm being too impatient? It takes about 6-8 seconds to display the first <100 rows (with about 10 columns). Admittedly this isn't a huge amount of time but its a lot longer than say mysql/sqlite3.

Comment: @Gearóid: No, you are not impatient, that's very slow. I added an example to my answer.

Comment: Running psql from the command line and doing a simple select on the table is pretty much instantaneous which suggests its a connection to the Postgres server thats the issue? Please note that the database is local so this shouldnt be an issue. I've noticed that listing records in my application takes a long time too. Any ideas? Thanks for your help with this!

Comment: I should also point out that I recently upgraded from OS X Snow Leopard to Lion. Would the default postgreSQL install on Lion cause interference?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know about OS X.